# DLL guidelines for multi languages compatibility (VB, C#,C++ and Python)

Tags: c#, python, c++, vb.net, dll

I have an application that uses a certain set of DLL files, but I had to modify them to be python compatible.

For example,Python fails to call `**FunctionToBeCalled**` method in this DLL :

```
Namespace
   L SomeClass
        L SomeFunction

Namespace.SomeExtension
          L ClassToBeCalled
               L FunctionToBeCalled
```

For my future projects, I want to create libraries that are compatible with as many coding languages as possible (for the moment: VB, C#,C++ and Python)

Are their any guidelines to create/write a DLL that be accessed by any coding language?

PS: I write DLLs using .NET framework

Comment: If it is a corporate enviroment, deploying services that could be called from aplications developed in different languages would be an option you could consider

Comment: Yes exactly, it is a corporate environment, so I was wondering if there was a way to write a unique DLL that can be called from different platforms? if there is, what are the rules we have to respect so each language will be able to access the DLL?
It is hard to write several DLLs and debug them one by one for each application!

Comment: You could do some reading on [Service oriented architecture - implementation approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture#Implementation_approaches)

Comment: Stick to Standard `C` without extensions.  Or COM IDispatch (learning curve is much longer).